# Extract a variable string and a number from a string using java patterns and matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have a string, let say: 
`"The student John with the number 1 is smart."`

I want to extract the variable parts of this string: the name of the student and his number.

- `"The student John with the number 1 is smart."`
- `"The student Alan with the number 2 is smart."`

How should I create the regex? I know that `\\d` extract numbers, but how can I extract the string?

- `but for the "**H2k Gaming** (1st to **5** Kills)"`

  where the variable string is "H2k Gaming" and the variable number is 5

  ```
  String sentence = "H2k Gaming (1st to 5 Kills)";
  String pattern = "[\\w ]+ \\(1st to (\\d+) Kills\\)";
  ```

It prints:

```
Name: Gaming
Number: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String sentence = "The student John with the number 1 is smart.";
String pattern = "The student (\\w+) with the number (\\d+) is smart.";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(sentence);

if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Number: " + m.group(2));
}
```

[See it in action](https://repl.it/BgDe/0)

Comment: @NellyJunior, in this case it wont work because `H2k Gaming` has space in it. `\w` matches a letter, a digit or a dash. To add the space, you can replace `\\w+` with `[\\w ]+`. This creates a character set, which accepts `\\w` and spaces.

Comment: I have edited the question. for the rest of it doesn't work. Can you tell me why? Thank you!

Comment: @NellyJunior, you still have to put `()` around the character set. [See the updated version](https://repl.it/BgDe/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the string always has the same format, you can simply split by `" "` and access the right indices:

```
String[] tokens = text.split(" ");
String name = tokens[2];
int number = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the form is constant, just get the blanks.

`^The student (.*) with the number (.*) is smart\.$`